# Can I get the Kodak DVC323 webcam to work?

Tags: webcam

I have an older webcam, a Kodak DVC323 Digital Video Camera, that I'm trying to get to work with the Raspberry Pi, running Raspian. It's rated 5V 0.5A. I see it is not on the list of verified peripherals.

It is showing up on lsusb, but /dev/video0 does not get created. Therefore neither fswebcam nor pygame.camera can access it.

Are there any generic webcam drivers or something I can get?

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 040a:0001 Kodak Co. DVC-323

fswebcam
--- Opening /dev/video0...
stat: No such file or directory

>>>python
>>>import pygame.camera
>>>pygame.camera.init()
>>>pygame.camera.list_cameras()
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Google for your camera support on ANY Linux platform, if there's any, install that version of Linux on your PC and play with the camera, check the drivers and see if the software you need works. Only after you have checked it works properly, you may try to find Raspberry Pi related drivers/settings, because if there's no Linux support, the chances are it has no Raspbian support as well.